# MySQL: обновление счета, при попытке вставки уже существующего игрока

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть запрос:

```
INSERT INTO `DonateCoins` (`player`, `donateCoins`) VALUES ('test', '20202')
```

Как сделать, чтобы при выполнении данного запроса, если такой `player` присутствует в таблице, то к его количеству коинов добавлялось 20202?

В самой таблице есть `player` - test и `donateCoins` - 0

Comment: google:// unique key insert update mysql, и привыкайте прикладывать результат  `show create table %tableName%` когда задаете sql-related вопросы, и указывайте точное название бд в теге. это mssql,sql, firebird, postgres?

Comment: Спасибо, что поправили сообщение.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно поступить следующим образом: индексируем столбец `player` уникальным индексом

```
ALTER TABLE
  DonateCoins
ADD UNIQUE KEY
  player (player);
```

Это не позволит вставлять в таблицу `DonateCoins` дублирующие записи. Вставку новых данных осуществляем INSERT-запросом с `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, в которой прописываем логику обновления поля при обнаружении вставки записи с уже существующим игроком.

```
INSERT INTO
  DonateCoins (`player`, `donateCoins`)
VALUES
  ('test', '20202')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  donateCoins = donateCoins + VALUES(donateCoins);
```

В результате, если запись уже существует, `donateCoins` будет увеличиваться на 20202 (тип столбца должен быть числовым, а не текстовым).

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробую.

UPD: работает, всё.